# Clean Code in Excel?

Tags: vb.net, excel, f#, functional-programming, comments

As a former programmer I like clean, maintainable and documented code.

As a project manager I have to do complex excels from time to time and want to write "clean" formulas in the same way I wrote programs.

1. (How) Can I add "comments" into a (multiline) formula?
2. (How) Can I "name" a (cell-relative) formula and reuse it? (e.g. write it as a vb (or even f#) function with parameters)

Example1: Instead of

```
=IF(AND(L$11+(L$13-1)*7>=$C15;L$11+(L$13-1)*7<$D15);VLOOKUP($A15;RessourcePlan;12+$E15;WRONG);0)
```

I'd like to write:

```
// check if this columns (L) date is inbetween startdate (Col C) and enddate (Col D)
=IF (AND(L$11+(L$13-1)*7>=$C15;L$11+(L$13-1)*7<$D15);

    // then select the the utilisation (12+E15) for the resp. team from the resource plan
    VLOOKUP($A15;RessourcePlan;12+$E15;WRONG);

    // else default to 0
    0 

) //ENDIF
```

And instead of example1 I might write a user defined function (UDF)

```
Function Utilization(thisDate As Date, task As String) As Double
    ... // clean VB or F# code
End Function
```

And then write

```
=Utilization(L11,A15)
```

Comment: IMHO its better than the overly complex oneliner, whose meaning / inner workings I cannot remember some days after writing it. Ill add an example ...

Comment: have you tried using the excel interop for .net?

Comment: Any chance you could use FCell http://fcell.io :-)? It came to my mind immediately when I saw a question tagged with `f#` and `excel`. It lets you write F# code behind for Excel...

Comment: Sadly not. I've looked at it, but my organization is too big, and my impact too small :-)

Comment: @TomasPetricek When you have the purely functional mindset, you can draw advantage also in simpler languages. See for example my post on implementing haskell's type "Either A B" in Java or the Functional Java initiative. The only thing is that the compiler will not force you to stick to the paradigms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a former **functional** programmer, I came up with the user defined functions given below for my problem.

Note the following points:

- I only write "pure" mathematical functions that map in-params to
  results, no state-changes, input/output, for-loops or similar
  involved. (At least I have this in mind, "Let" and VBA is obviously not "pure"..)
- cell referencing and auto-completion is to be done in the sheets (excel is strong here)
- constants are defined as named ranges in a special sheet called "Constants"

Given a task with an estimated effort and start and end-date, how many ppl do I need? => 100% means one person needs to work on this full-time (assuming she is working x daysPerWeek, as fixed in the constants)

```
Public Function util(ByVal startDate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date, ByVal estimation As Double) As Double

 Dim duration As Integer
 Let duration = DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate)

 Dim weeks As Double
 Let weeks = duration / 7

 Dim pdays As Integer
 Let pdays = weeks * [daysPerWeek]

 util = estimation / pdays

End Function
```

Since I have many tasks and many teams working on them, I'd like to know how many ppl from a team I need for a task. The following function reuses the function from above. Note the readable names for the complex Vlookup-calls and the reference to "BaseLine1" which is my actual project plan. It will be very easy to extend this to get other scenarios etc.

```
Public Function currentUtil(currentDate As Date, id As String, team As Integer) As Double
  Dim result As Double

  Let startDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(id, [BaseLine1], 11, 0)
  Let endDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(id, [BaseLine1], 12, 0)
  Let estimation = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(id, [BaseLine1], 5 + team, 0)

  If (currentDate >= startDate And currentDate < endDate) Then
    result = util(startDate, endDate, estimation)
  Else
    result = 0
  End If

  currentUtil = result

End Function
```

Finally I use it in the following way: I have a main table with all tasks including their dates and estimated efforts per team. In another sheet, I have the weeks on the horizontal and the tasks per team on the vertical. In the cells I use the function "currentUtil" and use autocompletion and conditional formatting to get a analytical view on the plan.

Finally I have the same result as before, but in a much more convenient and maintainable form.