# How to implement higher-order function "map" in VBA

Tags: excel, haskell, vba

In [Clean Code in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363180/clean-code-in-excel) I looked for a cleaner way to implement complex user defined functions (UDF) in Excel/VBA.

So, assume I have implemented a function `f: A -> B` as a UDF in Excel. Lets further assume I have 10 A-values in cells A1:A10 and `"=f(A1)"` in cell B1, autocompleted down to cell B10.

Now, when a new A-value arrives, then I have to do two things:

1. add the value to new cell A11 and
2. **extend the autocompletion in column B by a call to A11**.

Because I have many functions in my workbook that refer back to A-values, I would like to automate the second step.

In my functional/Haskell thinking I would have a list of `as` and would represent the list of bs as

```
bs = map f as
```

so when ever I have a changed set of `as`, `bs` would be updated whenever it's reevaluated.

I am quite sure this can be implemented cleanly in standard Excel/VBA with named ranges. I imagine the following:

- have a named range NamedAs:="A1:A10"
- in cell B1 only one call to the VBA version of `map f NamedAs`
- this call automagically autocompletes down foreach element of "NamedAs"

Then, when I add a new A-value to the range "NamedAs" and reevaluate the worksheet, I would be all done. ( I would not need to change the call in column B, only force reevaluation )

**How can the VBA version of "map f NamedRange" be implemented ??**

*PS: While writing, it seems to me that this question is more about the definition / usage of functions that return ranges - higher-orderness might be a secondary yet interesting topic ...*

*PPS: I wonder if there are people that are verbose both in FP / Haskell and in VBA :-)*

*PPPS: No, I cannot use FCell.*

Comment: I've tried this before and have hit road blocks due to VBA's antiquated type system.  There aren't really function pointers in the language at all, so good luck. (Also, yes, there are a few of us who are competent in Haskell and VBA =P)

Comment: Excel offers the `Table` which can provide a calculation that is based on values in the current row.  Those formulas will automatically extend when rows are added (or removed).  In VBA, this can be done by hooking into the WorksheetChange event and adding new formulas if changes to a given range are noticed.  It might be possible to create a class module with these events built in to allow for reuse of the code within a workbook.

Comment: @Byron Wall:  interesting, but events and WorksheetCHange does not sound very "functional"? Or do I miss the point? can you give an example?

Comment: You might be able to hide some of the event code in a class module which could then be instantiated as needed.  You are likely going to be disappointed with your options implementing this though.

Comment: Regarding the first "PS" it seems array formula (multi-cell) is the answer. When I add it to the complete target column with "Ctrl-SHift-Enter", Excel auto-reevaluates the formula when the definition column changes. But: It seems to be very inefficient / imperformant !?

Comment: Apparently there are hacky ways to get around the lack or first-class function pointers. See http://unlimitedexcel.blogspot.com/2011/12/pointers-in-vba-huhh-delegates-in-vba.html